# Install a theme with its demo content -- via command line?

Tags: theming

The tutorials I've seen all want me to use phpMyAdmin. Here is an example that's very apropos since my theme is Zircon.
https://www.weebpal.com/guides/step-step-guide-install-drupal-8-theme
AFAIK I don't have MyPHPAdmin and I don't have access to it. What I do have is sudo access on the Ubuntu 16.04 server.
I'm using Drupal 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the database using drush rather than phpMyAdmin.

Create a standard drupal 8 site, go to the /sites/default directory and run

```
drush sql-cli < databasefilename.sql
```

See the importing database section here http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/use-drush-export-import-drupal-mysql-database-dump-file

Comment: Thanks! Okay I ran into this and I've asked the developers of Zircon about how to get around this, but... ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 542: Unknown column 'content_translation_source' in 'field list'
-- any idea on this? I get the gist of it, unknown column, but that's all

Comment: Hard to say.. It smells like a missing field but that of that would be stored in the database so should be there. Did you hear back from them?

Comment: They asked for more info. Is there a standard place I would find the db it's trying to import INTO in order to see the field list and confirm the fact that it doesn't match up? I haven't had any luck in my searches on that

Comment: so I found out how to get into phpMyAdmin via ISPConfig. Annoyingly I can't try it through there because the server won't import bigger than 2MB and the sample db is 4MB. I'm working on working my way around that now